# array1(1:A)=array2(1:C,D) Fortran 90 what is the function of the colon

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I am not 100% what the role of the `1:` is here.  At which index to start the copy?  But then why not two such parameters for the rank 2 array?

Comment: That's not a semicolon, ':' is a colon.

Answer (score 2):

To be a little more explicit:

In Fortran90 and up you access a single array value by giving a single index, and access a subarray (a window of the array) by giving a range of indices separated by a colon.

```
a(1) = 0. 
a(2:5) = (/3.14,2.71,1.62,0./)
```

You can also give a step size.

```
a(1:5:2) = (/0,2.71,0./)
```

And finally, you can leave out values and a default will be inserted. So if `a` runs from index 1 to 5 then I could write the above as

```
a(::2) = (/0,2.71,0./)
```

and the 1 and 5 are implied. Obviously, you shouldn't leave these out if it makes the code unclear.

With a multidimensional array, you can mix and match these on each dimension, as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You're taking a slice of `array2`, namely the elements in the `D`'th column from row `1` to `C` and putting them in the slice of `array1` which is elements `1` through `A`

So both slices are 1-dimensional arrays

Slice may not be the correct term in Fortran